# Room (SQLite) replacement strategy on entities with null values doesn't work

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have entity class `Person` and there should be no more than one person in the table with the same `name` and `feature`. However, if I set person's name or feature to null it doesn't work. How can I make it work with null values? See code below.

**TEST**

```java
Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
AppDb db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, AppDb.class).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
PersonDao dao = db.personDao();

// replacement works here
dao.insert(new Person("Musk", "Alien"));
dao.insert(new Person("Musk", "Alien"));

// replacement doesn't work here
dao.insert(new Person("Trump", null));
dao.insert(new Person("Trump", null));

// fails - actual size = 3 (Musk, Trump, Trump)
assertEquals(2, dao.getAll().size());
```

**Person.java**

```java
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.Index;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "person", indices = {@Index(value = {"name", "feature"}, unique = true)})
public class Person {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") private String name;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "feature") private String feature;

    public Person(String name, String feature) {
        this.name = name;
        this.feature = feature;
    }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public int getId() { return id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getFeature() { return feature; }
}
```

**PersonDao.java**

```java
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy;
import androidx.room.Query;
import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface PersonDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(Person person);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM person")
    List<Person> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM person WHERE feature = :feature")
    List<Person> getByFeature(String feature);

}
```

**AppDb.java**

```java
import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

@Database(
        version = 1,
        exportSchema = false,
        entities = {Person.class}
)
public abstract class AppDb extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract PersonDao personDao();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A `null` value is unique from any other `null` value](https://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html), which is why no `UNIQUE` constrain violation occurs such that a replace has to be done.

You can make your `feature` field `@NonNull` such that null is not a valid value, and if its empty then you can use a default/magic value such as `"NONE"`.

Or if you don't really use `id` then you can remove it and change your `PRIMARY KEY` to be the `name` field, such that inserts of `Person` with the same-name but different feature are replaced.